# Angular 8: Drawing two bar-charts in ng2-charts not working with different data sets

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-charts

I was trying to draw two charts on the same page  using the code below in the HTTP

```
<div class="chk-block-content">
    <canvas height="100"width="500" baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [colors]="barChartColors" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType"></canvas>

</div>

 <div class="chk-block-content">
    <canvas height="100"width="500" baseChart [datasets]="barChartData2" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [colors]="barChartColors" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="bar"></canvas>
</div>
```

in two diferent blocks , however the only data set that is drawn in the screen is the barChartData  one.I have defined them like this in my component ts

```
 public barChartdata2: any[]=[
      {data: [10], label: 'Series A'},
      {data: [10], label: 'Series B'}
   ]
   public barChartLabels:string[] = [ 'Enero', 


 'Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'];
   public barChartType:string = 'bar';
   public barChartLegend:boolean = false;
   public barChartData:any[] = [
     {data: [6500, 590, 800, 810, 560, 550, 400], label: 'Series A'},
     {data: [2800, 480, 400, 190, 860, 207, 900], label: 'Series B'}
   ];
```

Why does barChartData only get drawn?

Is there a way for me to visualize both datasets?

Comment: any error on the console?

Comment: None at all , it just doesnt show anything on the canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- in your TS file, the variable name is `barChartdata2`, while the variable referred to in the 2nd chart is `barChartData2` (capital D)
- the chart type of `bar` in your HTML should be `barChartType`

relevant **HTML**:

```
<div class="chk-block-content">
    <canvas height="100"width="500" baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [colors]="barChartColors" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType"></canvas>
</div>

 <div class="chk-block-content">
    <canvas height="100"width="500" baseChart [datasets]="barChartData2" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [colors]="barChartColors" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType"></canvas>
</div>
```

relevant **TS** file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from "chart.js";
import { Label } from "ng2-charts";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
public barChartData2: any[]=[
      {data: [10], label: 'Series A'},
      {data: [10], label: 'Series B'}
  /*
     {data: [6500, 590, 800, 810, 560, 550, 400], label: 'Series A'},
     {data: [2800, 480, 400, 190, 860, 207, 900], label: 'Series B'}
   */
   ];
   public barChartLabels:string[] = [ 'Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'];
   public barChartType:string = 'bar';
   public barChartLegend:boolean = false;
   public barChartData:any[] = [
     {data: [6500, 590, 800, 810, 560, 550, 400], label: 'Series A'},
     {data: [2800, 480, 400, 190, 860, 207, 900], label: 'Series B'}
   ];
  constructor() {  }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-template-vvbwx3)

Comment: thank you im pretty new to frontend with angular and still make some pretty beginner mistakes